# System.Expression.Interactions.dll does not include CallMethodAction

Tags: expression-blend-4

I have recently just installed `Expression Blend 4` Ultimate to run along side my Visual Studio 2010. I have included the reference for System.Expression.Interactions.dll but it does not include the CallMethodAction within the reference. Does anyone know why? I have been searching all night and have not come across any good sites that explain why. All sites I have read and been to just say that the reference is needed to use the callMethodAction. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Sounds like you're missing the namespace declared in your UserControl or whatever you're using, (though not sure, so not submitted as answer just a comment) like xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"